# Blender 2.8 Focus view on selection

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

When i press `.` view goes to center (no matter which object i selected) and not to selected face/object. Is it bug or what?

Comment: I investigated more and found out that problem is with my .blend file. When i create new everything work fine. But this file on different machines behave the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending collection from broken file to new did the trick. Everything works fine now